# Convert Row in to DateTime DataTypes Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe that have a row that have date&time information not column, I want to convert it to DateTime Datatype. I was able to change the single row but could not be able to save it to dataframe. Below is my trial for the same. Please let me know missing part of code. Also not usre how to ignore the column which does not have time information(like column 0).

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({0: {0: 'A', 1: 'Timestamp', 2: 'B', 3: 'C', 4: 'D'}, 1: {0: '1-2.1', 1: '11/25/2020 2:34:25 PM', 2: 21, 3: 42, 4: 971}, 2: {0: '1-2.2', 1: 'Wed Nov 25 17:30:12 2020', 2: 21, 3: 42, 4: 971}, 3: {0: '1-1.1', 1: '11/30/2020 11:48:38 AM', 2: 20.9, 3: 29.9, 4: 957.9}, 4: {0: '1-1.1', 1: 'Mon Nov 30 13:39:00 2020', 2: 20.9, 3: 29.9, 4: 957.9}})

a = numpy.where(df.values == 'Timestamp')
R_Ele = a[0][0]
C_Ele = a[1][0]
print ("Row:",a[0][0])
print ("Column:",a[1][0])

df.loc[R_Ele] = pandas.to_datetime(df.loc[R_Ele])

print (df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should transpose your df to get it right:

```
df1 = df.iloc[:,1:].T
df1.columns = df[0]
df1.Timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df1.Timestamp)
```

Result:

```
0      A           Timestamp     B     C      D
1  1-2.1 2020-11-25 14:34:25    21    42    971
2  1-2.2 2020-11-25 17:30:12    21    42    971
3  1-1.1 2020-11-30 11:48:38  20.9  29.9  957.9
4  1-1.1 2020-11-30 13:39:00  20.9  29.9  957.9
```

---

If you really want to use your dataframe as is you can do:

```
df.loc[1,1:] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[1,1:])
```

Comment: Nope, I need to do it without transpose. i get this one but it changes few column data too...df.loc[1] = pandas.to_datetime(df.loc[1].iloc[1:])

Comment: That is correct. Thanks, Dear It works great